# How to pass results from slow sql query in runtime

Tags: sql, dynamic

Is there any way to load results from a query that takes more than a minute to return results?

Let me elaborate on the situation. I have a SQL query which is very convoluted. it has multiple join on different on 5 different tables because of the level of normalization involved.

So my query return around 6k records, however it takes more than a minute to fetch these records.

This does not look good on a website that a user has to wait for more than minute for a page to load. So is there any way i can pass the results in real time as the query is getting executed? Rather than waiting for the entire query to be completed. I hope everybody understands the point I'm trying to make here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you've not specified what DBMS or web platform you're using, in general this will not be possible if you are using an ORDER BY in your query, as this will require the whole resultset in order to work.

It sounds like you should instead focus on optimising your query, or getting the results cached so that you don't need to run it every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better option is to create a "view  table", and then only return the result of the view. I think, this option decrease the time of your query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your system, but I will try give you some advices.

You can load the page without records, if possible, and load them with ajax and insert rows dynamically.

Other possibility is to do this query as the first step at your backend, but asynchronous, and get result at last step. It will reduce this time, probably, because the query would execute parallel with other steps.

Obviously you should try too optimize the query and apply some cache method, as @richard said.

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination, in sql we have Limit and offset see if u can use them refer this [link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm) for example